# What is the role of the resistors in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, adc

[image]

The evaluation boards I found put a resistor in series on each of the ADC's digital outputs. Can someone please explain to me what is the purpose of these resistors? Is it necessary or can I just not use them in my design?

Also, the two evaluation boards I found use different values. One uses 10 Ω while the other uses 22 Ω. So, If I add this to my PCB, how can I calculate the required resistance value?

For further details:

- The ADC is [AD9226](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9226.pdf). It is a 12-bit ADC with parallel CMOS output. Figure 22 of its datasheet (page 23) shows one example of the use of the resistors (RP1 and RP2).
- I planned to use [Arty Z7 20](https://digilent.com/shop/arty-z7-zynq-7000-soc-development-board/) to read the ADC's digital outputs. The ADC will be on my custom PCB and connected to the Arty through its headers (I put male headers that are compatible with the Arty's headers). The ADC will be clocked using an external 25 MHz clock generator. The signals' logic level will be 3.3 V.

Comment: MCU inputs have some capacity since they are made from Fets so it’s good to charge this capacity with current limiting.

Comment: They are probably series terminators. We need more information to decide if they are needed. How long are the signals? On the same board, or connected by a cable? Are they parallel data or serial data? Add signal names.

Comment: This is an advanced project so you should really learn about transmission lines and signal integrity. The resistor value is only part of the story. This is a good book: *High Speed Digital Design: A Handbook of Black Magic*. https://www.amazon.com/High-Speed-Digital-Design-Handbook/dp/0133957241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistors are source terminators. For a source terminator to be effective, the total source impedance must equal the characteristic impedance of the transmission line (the PCB trace in this case).

Most PCB traces on high-speed boards are either stripline or microstrip. Search for these terms to learn more. A typical PCB characteristic impedance is about 50 ohms (single-ended signal).

The total source impedance is equal to the equivalent impedance of the driving IC plus the series resistor.

The impedance of the driving IC is not something that is normally specified in the datasheet. You usually have to derive it from I-V curves or measure it.

So, for your example, these might be the values. Transmission line: 50 ohms. Driving IC: 28 ohms.

50 - 28 = 22 ohm resistor.

Buy the book recommended in my comment. Or, if you don't want to spent $100US, dig around the internet and try to learn it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Without more details, such as the ADC and MCU being used and the board layout, it's difficult to say for sure.  But two reasons come to my mind.

1. They are there to limit the current flow from the output of the ADC through the protection or parasitic diodes between the inputs of the MCU and Vdd, if it's possible for the ADC to power up before the MCU.
2. They are source (back) series termination resistors to reduce or eliminate ringing on the high speed digital lines.

Comment: The AD9226 is a 65 MSPS part, thus, source termination resistors make sense since the output edges will have a fast rise time.